# Regular Expressions - Not matching specified length

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
[a-z][^b|j|m|n]{5}
```

However, it only matches 6 characters and not the specified 5?

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using?

Comment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 5):

`[^b|j|m|n]{5}` would match 5 characters, and `[a-z]` would be the 6th.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to use

```
[ac-iklo-z]{5}
```

instead.  This will only match the desired characters for all five characters.  If you really do want to match "any alphabetic character followed by any single character except b,j,m,n" for a total of five characters, it would be

```
[a-z][^bjmn]{4}
```